# Задать значение поля если оно есть и сделать его статичным

Tags: mysql, mysqli

При выполнении запроса со связкой, со второй таблицей через left join

Из второй таблицы выбираем в том случаи если есть связка. То есть на выходе получаем некоторые массивы с полями из второй таблицы.

Вопрос. Возможно ли задать значение поля статичным в том случаи если оно есть. То есть если есть связка со второй таблицей? Через as возможно переименовать поле, но что если необходимо задать этому полю статичное значение. Или и переименовать и задать статичное значение?

```
SELECT t.*, p.id_us as 'podpis' FROM tag_stats t
left JOIN user_podp p  on p.id_b = t.id and p.types = 'tag' and p.id_us = '{$user['id']}'
```

Выхватываем запись из второй таблицы если есть связка. Поле id_us расположено во второй таблице, необходимо задать так чтобы при связке имело статичное значение не зависимо от его содержимого. через константу переименовываем поле во избежании дублей если они имеются во второй таблице.

Необходимо, чтобы на выходе получить статичное значение поля podpis, любое(числительное, строка и тд). Главное чтобы было неизменным если имеется связка. Без связки можно не выводить.

php нежелательно нагружать условиями если возможно получить при выполнении запроса.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. попробуйте привести пример входных данных и ожидаемого результата. Если вы про поля непосредственно выводящиеся в select то конечно вы можете задать константу например `5 as five`. И если вас в принципе интересуют записи только по связке то вам нужен обычный join а не left join

Comment: 5 as five, так мы переименуем поле, но значение будет динамичным при его наличии в бд. Да, в select, возможно сделать значение поля при пересечении статичным?

Comment: Дополнил примером

Comment: Ну оно и так при выводе будет всегда равно $user['id'] если связь есть и NULL есть нет. по моему все ваши пожелания выполняются

Comment: А задать в селекте несуществующее поле и задать его значение, при условии что есть связка, возможно? Или поступить иначе, чтобы не выносить условие в php

Comment: На выводе sql количество полей всегда фиксировано, вы только управляете их содержимым. Т.е. поле если вы его делаете будет всегда. А так можете написать в фразе select `case when p.id_us is not null then 'Связка есть поэтому тут это значение' else NULL end as New_field`